# Is there a Christian sect that believes only The New Testament and only Christ is God and The Whole Trinity exists in Him?

Tags: trinity, christology, oneness-pentecostalism, biblical-theology, marcion

"For in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily." - Colossians 2:9

Comment: You mean only the Bible? The New Testament constantly references the Old Testament—it is the Old Testament which is the referent of the word "the scriptures" in the New Testament! Also, according to Trinitarian theology, the fullness of the Godhead is in each person of the Trinity; it doesn't mean for Christ to have the fullness of the divinity in Him that He must be all three persons of the Trinity.

Comment: I'm not here to argue theology with you, I'm asking if there is a Christian sect with those beliefs (whether they are correct or wrong). By the way, I find it interesting that I got two votes down so far just for asking a question, even though it's just a question without any claims nor errors about facts or truth. People are voting with biases of their personal emotions rather than with reason.

Comment: [Cathars](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/43483/1787) rejected the Old Testament.

Comment: I'm not sure why some are voting to close this question based on "unclear what you're asking". It's clear to me.

Comment: @God_Is_Love For the record, I am not a contributor to abovementioned downvotes; I tend to seek clarification before I decide the question is unworthy of the site—I'm still unclear as to what you mean when you say, "only the New Testament." There is no New Testament which does not import the entirety of the Old Testament. Clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of a denomination that believes only the four gospel accounts in the New Testament, but cannot find the source.  I am unaware of any denomination that believes in only the New Testament.  From an answer you posted previously you said:

> Jesus revealed The Merciful Heavenly Father through His Teachings in the clearest way while The Old Testament did not, therefore we can go with sola scriptura when it comes to The Sayings of Jesus. Even then, sola fide must come first since a person must first believe that Jesus is The True Voice that reveals God The Father in order to trust His Teachings in The Gospel: "All things are delivered to me of my Father: and no man knoweth who the Son is, but the Father; and who the Father is, but the Son, and he to whom the Son will reveal him." (Luke 10:22) Source: [What was first, sola scriptura or sola fide?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53786/what-was-first-sola-scriptura-or-sola-fide/69001#69001)

However, with regard to a denomination that believes only Christ is God, then I would suggest Oneness Pentecostals.

> Oneness Pentecostals believe that there is but one God, a singular divine Spirit, who manifests himself as Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. This one indivisible God has no distinction of persons in God's eternal essence, and Jesus Christ is the manifestation, human personification, or incarnation of the one God.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneness_Pentecostalism

The United Pentecostal Church International, the largest Oneness Pentecostal denomination, says there is one God, who has revealed Himself as the Father, in His Son Jesus Christ, and as the Holy Spirit.  Jesus Christ is God manifested in flesh. He is both God and man.

> Oneness believers hold that God is absolutely and indivisibly one (Deuteronomy 6:4), and do not accept the idea of three distinct centers of consciousness in the Godhead. They also affirm that in Jesus dwells all the fullness of the Godhead bodily and that Jesus is the only name given for salvation (Colossians 2:9). The Father was revealed to the world in the name of Jesus, the Son was given the name of Jesus at birth, and the Holy Spirit comes to believers in the name of Jesus. Thus they believe the apostles correctly fulfilled Christ's command to baptize “in the name [singular] of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost” by baptizing all converts with the invocation of the name of Jesus (Matthew 28:19; Acts 2:38; 8:16; 10:48; 19:5; 22:16).
>
> Oneness believers affirm that God has revealed Himself as Father (in parental relationship to humanity), in the Son (in human flesh), and as the Holy Spirit (in spiritual action). They acknowledge that the one God existed as Father, Word, and Holy Spirit before His incarnation as Jesus Christ, the Son of God; and that while Jesus walked on earth as God Himself incarnate, the Spirit of God continued to be omnipresent.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Pentecostal_Church_International#Godhead

Comment: What about believing that there aren't different modes of God but that The Three all exist eternally as One? The Father as The Eternal Mind of God, The Son as The Eternal Image of God and The Holy Spirit as The Eternal Spirit of God, all existing in One Eternal God, Christ, and that we were made in His Image with Mind and Body and Spirit.

Comment: What about it? You asked if there was a Christian sect that believes only Christ is God and the whole Trinity exists in Him.  As far as I can see, I've answered your question. My personal opinions on the Jesus Only Oneness Pentecostal views about the Trinity have nothing to do with anything. Personal opinions are not encouraged on Christianity Stack.

Comment: You did answer the question, then I asked if there is a sect that isn't moralistic. The hostility isn't necessary.

Comment: Sorry, but you've completely lost me with your last comment saying you asked "if there is a sect that isn't moralistic". And I'm not being hostile and I did not down-vote your question. I'm afraid I simply don't understand what you are now asking.

Comment: Not moralistic but modalistic. Sorry, I couldn't edit the post. I was thinking about a non-modalistic belief in Jesus Christ as the one God. A belief that only Christ is God and The Holy Trinity is revealed and exists within Him.

Comment: Okay, I'm with you now! However, the subject of modalism and those who oppose it  has probably already been covered in detail elsewhere on Christianity Stack.  I will take a look and see if I can find anything....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97305/discussion-between-lesley-and-god-is-love).